# Validation errors always show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a validation code for a date that always show, wether the condition is true or false. It is called this way.

```
      validate :ensure_birth_date_range, if: lambda { mentee? && born_on.present? }    
      # Check if the year of birth is in range
      def ensure_birth_date_range
        minimum = Application::MENTEE_AGE_RANGE_MIN.years.ago
        maximum = Application::MENTEE_AGE_RANGE_MAX.years.ago
        errors.add(:born_on, :invalid) unless born_on.between?(minimum, maximum)
      end
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean ?  I can see that the parameters are sent right from the logs and I know for trying it that if I manually change the year for an invalid one it will be resetted, which is not the case if it is a valid year. Can I do more ?

Comment: check this: https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger

Comment: My ruby version is 2.1, this link would not work.

Comment: you can use https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `MENTEE_AGE_RANGE_MIN` < `MENTEE_AGE_RANGE_MAX`, your code will *always* produce a `minimum` date that is *after* the `maximum` date. Thus, asking whether any date is `between?(minimum, maximum)` will *always* yield `false`.

`4.between?(3, 5)` will return `true` but 
`4.between?(5, 3)` will return `false`.

Swapping min and max should do, like so:

```
def ensure_birth_date_range
  earliest = Application::MENTEE_AGE_RANGE_MAX.years.ago
  latest   = Application::MENTEE_AGE_RANGE_MIN.years.ago
  errors.add(:born_on, :invalid) unless born_on.between?(earliest, latest)
end
```

HTH!

Comment: Now you say it, it seems obvious. Thank you ;)